# issues with php if statement within foreach loop

Tags: php, if-statement, foreach

I did have a quick search on this but couldn't find anything relating to my problem. I'm having issues with an if statement within a foreach loop. I'm pulling a list of categories from one class, and a single category to be selected from another. The code below (with the if statement removed) works perfectly, and returns 12 options with populated values.

```
foreach ($user_info->categories as $key=>$category) {
    $category_name = $user_info->category_names[$key];
    echo '<option value="'.$category.'">'.$category_name.'</option>';
}
```

However when I add the if statement inside as below:

```
foreach ($user_info->categories as $key=>$category) {
    $category_name = $user_info->category_names[$key];
    if ($category = $get_article_info->category_1) {
        echo '<option value="'.$category.'" selected="selected">'.$category_name.'</option>';
    } else {
        echo '<option value="'.$category.'">'.$category_name.'</option>';
    }
}
```

I get a list of options with the text populated but all twelve options have value="".  $get_article_info->category_1 works when echoed on it's own, and even if it were not found I would expect the if statement to echo 12 options without any selected (the same as the first code example).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using `=` instead of `==`  You should change

```
 if ($category = $get_article_info->category_1) {
```

To

```
  if ($category == $get_article_info->category_1) {
```

Comment: Spot on! Cheers for that, minor oversight.